# multiple Promises in nodejs wait till they all finish

Tags: node.js, promise, coinbase-api

I have this snippet of code in my nodejs application.

The problem is that it doesn't wait before it renders the config page and passes the object thebalances.

```
app.get("/config", (req, res) => {
    var thebalances = [];
    client.rest.account.listAccounts().then(accounts => {

        accounts.forEach(element => {
            client.rest.product.getProductTicker(element.currency + '-USD').then(priceInfo => {

                thebalances.push({
                    currency: element.currency
            });
        });
        res.render("config", { balance: thebalances });
    })
});
```

I have modified it to this now: but i think it errors out on some and like mentioned below it is all failing.

```
// GET /about
app.get("/config", (req, res) => {
    let thebalances = [];
    client.rest.account.listAccounts().then(async accounts => {
        let promises = [];
        accounts.forEach(element => {
            promises.push(client.rest.product.getProductTicker(element.currency + '-USD'));
        });
        await Promise.all(promises).then(
            results => {
                results.forEach(priceInfo => {
                    thebalances.push({ currency: element.currency });
                });
            }
        ).catch(
            error => {}
        )
        console.log(results);
        res.render("config", { balances: thebalances });
    })
});
```

I'm not sure how i can handle the multiple variable# of promises inside the foreach loop. I need to let that do its thing first before i can render the config page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using coinbase api.

Comment: You need to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: but its an unknown number of promises, so within the forEach loop it could be 3 it could be 30 how would i structure that?

Comment: The number of promises doesn't need to be fixed, any array of accounts will work: `Promise.all(accounts.map(...))`

Comment: Okay i understand the promise.all documentation but its unclear how i would make that work with my specific scenario, you mention accounts.map <- what is this exactly I dont see map anywhere in the doc? Can you structure my code snippet with a promise.all?

Comment: Hard to advise. As currently written, you go to the trouble of fetching various `priceInfo`, but then don't use it. Presumably `priceInfo`, or some property thereof, should be rendered?

Comment: In the second attempt, you try to use `element ` when it's not in scope. First attempt is better (in that regard).

Comment: Correct for simplicity i left that part out but yes i do grab some data from priceInfo. Do you mind creating a working snippet on how you would get this to work please.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.rest.account.listAccounts().then(async accounts => {
    let promises = [];
    accounts.forEach(element => {
        promises.push(client.rest.product.getProductTicker(element.currency + '-USD'));
    });
    await Promise.all(promises).then(
        results => {
            results.forEach(priceInfo  => {
                thebalances.push({currency: element.currency});
            });
        }
    ).catch(
        error => {
        }
    )
    res.render("config", { balance: thebalances });
```

Please read up on this ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

There's some con with using Promise.all if one fail its fail.

edit: missing await

Comment: I think that might be what is happening I cannot console.log any of the reuslts or the variable thebalances

Comment: How would i get around the if one fails it as a whole fails?

Comment: look under the Promise all document #Promise.all fail-fast behaviour right at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

If it's really the case that one or more promise is failing, and it's really the case that this is okay from an app perspective, then...

```
// ...
let promises = accounts.map(element => {
    return getProductTicker(element.currency);
});
// ...


function getProductTicker(currency) {
    return client.rest.product.getProductTicker(currency + '-USD').catch(error => {
        // debug here, if the error is a problem, otherwise
        return null
    })
}
```

Now promise all will contain proper resolutions of `getProductTicker` as well as nulls wherever that call failed.  To clean it up...

```
await Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    let maybeWeShouldDebugHere = results.filter(r => !!!r)
})
```

Comment: hmm this looks like it will change my snippet, can you implement your suggestion into my snippet to see how it would look please